# How gzip compression still happening?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`,`Apache/2.4.7` and `PHP 5.5.9`. I installed Wordpress `4.4.2` in my machine.

When I run my site in `localhost`, I noticed that `js/css` are compressed in `gzip` format. I didn't install any minifier plugin in my site. Also in `php.ini` it is set like `zlib.output_compression = Off`. I checked in both `.htaccess` and `apache2.conf`, nothing is configured for `gzip` compression.

Can anybody point out how it is coming?

Comment: Check for `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE` in your Apache config. JS and CSS are probably still mentioned there. Note that it's usually a good idea to use compression, it improves the loading speed of your site.

Comment: if you mean in `apache2.conf`,it is not there.I know compression is good but needed to know how it is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache 2.4 under Ubuntu 14.04, the default deflate.conf file contains:

```
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

and

```
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
```

which add the gzip compression. This is different than using a "minifier" program, which basically rewrites text files by getting rid of whitespace.

Comment: how to disable for testing?just by removing those lines?

Comment: Either comment out those lines or, in a more broadbrush approach, dismod deflate and restart Apache. I would just comment out the lines that you are testing against.

Comment: I commented like this `#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript`,and restarted `apache` but `js` files are still showing as `gzip`

Comment: Depending on how your html is written, your `js` files may seen by deflate as `text/html` or `text/plain`. You might try commenting out `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml` as well. If not, you can try to comment out all directives in `deflate.conf`. If that doesn't make it stop, then it would appear that the directive has been added elsewhere. You could confirm that the deflate module is doing the compression by dismod'ing deflate.

Comment: surprisingly I didn't comment it in `.htaccess`